# Pandas keep the latest rows for the same ID with some conditional column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I want to keep the latest rows with the same ID and also the rows that match certain column values. Sample Input:

```
ID          Timestamp       Survey Outcome
12          11/26/2021      INCOMPLETE Survey
95          11/26/2021      INCOMPLETE Survey
95          11/27/2021      COMPLETE Survey
95          11/28/2021      RANG-But did not connect
12          11/29/2021      COMPLETE Survey
24          11/26/2021      RANG-But did not connect
24          11/27/2021      INCOMPLETE Survey
95          11/28/2021      RANG-But did not connect
24          11/28/2021      INCOMPLETE Survey
```

Here ID 12 has two values, so I'll keep the latest(11/29/2021) row. But for ID 95, once the survey is complete it can't have any other options like *rang-but did not connect*. So I want to keep the latest timestamps data and also keep those rows where once the data is *complete survey* but the latest data shows *incomplete survey* or *did not connect* (all data after seeing *COMPLETE SURVEY*).

So my sample output will be:

````
ID          Timestamp       Survey Outcome
95          11/27/2021      COMPLETE Survey
95          11/28/2021      RANG-But did not connect
12          11/29/2021      COMPLETE Survey
95          11/28/2021      RANG-But did not connect
24          11/28/2021      INCOMPLETE Survey```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `ID` and `Timestamp` first, then use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) for all values after `COMPLETE Survey` and add last `ID` not matched by `isin` with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Timestamp'])

m = df['Survey Outcome'].eq('COMPLETE Survey')

df1 = df[m.groupby(df['ID']).cummax()]
df2 = df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')

df = df1.append(df2[~df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID'])]).sort_index()

print (df)
   ID  Timestamp            Survey Outcome
2  95 2021-11-27           COMPLETE Survey
3  95 2021-11-28  RANG-But did not connect
4  12 2021-11-29           COMPLETE Survey
7  95 2021-11-28  RANG-But did not connect
8  24 2021-11-28         INCOMPLETE Survey
```

Comment: it didn't work in my code!! it only keeps the last complete data.

Comment: @asifabdullah - Do you think in sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Timestamp']).reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x[x['Survey Outcome'] == 'COMPLETE Survey'].index[0]: ] if
                            x['Survey Outcome'].isin(['COMPLETE Survey']).any() else x.loc[x['Timestamp'].idxmax():]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
   ID  Timestamp            Survey Outcome
0  12 2021-11-29           COMPLETE Survey
1  24 2021-11-28         INCOMPLETE Survey
2  95 2021-11-27           COMPLETE Survey
3  95 2021-11-28  RANG-But did not connect
4  95 2021-11-28  RANG-But did not connect
```